# Ionic angular service --> Regular module to anonymous module

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to refactor the following service to an anonymous service:

```
angular.module('adress.services', [])   
.factory('Adresses', function () {

    var adresses = [
  {
      "ID": 1,
      "person": "Bladiebla",
      "name": "blabla",
  }];

    var service = {
        all: all,
        get: get
    };
    return service;


    function all() {
        return adresses;;
    }

    function get(adressId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < adresses.length; i++) {
            if (adresses[i].id === parseInt(adressId)) {
                return adresses[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Like this the service is working. When I refactor to the following it fails:

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module('adress.services')
        .factory('Adresses', Adresses);

    function Adresses() {
        var adresses = [
      {
            "ID": 1,
             "person": "Bladiebla",
             "name": "blabla",
       }];

        var service = {
            all: all,
            get: get
        };
        return service;

        function all() {
            return adresses;;
        }

        function get(adressId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < adresses.length; i++) {
                if (adresses[i].id === parseInt(adressId)) {
                    return adresses[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
})();
```

I'm not sure what Im missing in getting this to work. The service is loaded via the following master services file:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [
    'adress.services',
    'biography.services',
    'maps.services',
    'userplanning.services',
    'pageFocus.services',
    'timeline.services',
    'users.services',
    'questions.services'
]);
```

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('AdressesCtrl', function ($scope, Adresses) {
    $scope.adresses = Adresses.all();
})
```

I get the following error:

```
Module 'adress.services' is not available!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing dependency, i.e: [ ]

```
 angular
        .module('adress.services',[])
        .factory('Adresses', Adresses);
```

EDIT:
 AngularJS contains the following core types of objects and components:

```
Value
Factory
Service
Provider
Constant
```

These core types can be injected into each other using AngularJS dependency injection mechanism.

Comment: Ah yes, it works this way, thanks! I can't add the dependency via the $inject however as my example (http://briantroncone.com/?p=365) was showing. Now I see in the example there is also no dependency added to the module, only to the service, via inject. I first tried the following:
Adresses.$inject = [];
Why does this not work for me and why DOES it work when I add empy dependency to my module?

Comment: This is because, $inject add dependency to empty array. If you not provide that, it is not going to add. You can assume this '[ ]' as container that hold dependency. After adding [ ], you can inject dependency.

Comment: I realiser $inject adds dependency. But I'm saying that this way it actually does not work for me :/ 
I find it weird that the example at the website does use modules that do not have a [ ] parameter. I understand I will need to add dependency in one way or another, but why does it not work for me to do it solely via $inject?